JOIN seems to multiply rows
I have two tables:
Table 
Table 
I need to get info from table 1 and table 2 by id_banner (count of rows for equal id_banner is equal)
For example, getting info for id_banner = 51 will post 3 different rows from two tables, but for id_banner = 49 - two rows.
I made this request for id_banner = 51, but features_id and tag_list are duplicating.
SELECT 
  bs.id, bs.title_banner, bs.text_banner, bs.url_banner, bs.banner_state, bs.created_at, bs.updated_at, t.tag_list, t.features_id 
FROM 
  history_banenrs bs 
JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_banner) id_banner, tag_list, features_id FROM history_features WHERE id_banner = 51) t 
ON 
  bs.id_banner = t.id_banner;


Need help to make those columns not duplicating.

That's not how joining tables works for what you want to achieve. In this case there are 2 scenarios: either there is a different unique key (probably a compound key of multiple columns), either there is a third (or sometimes fourth) table that links the 2 tables in your sshots. There is, of course, a third scenario, where the design is bad and it's impossible to relate rows in-between each other, but I am optimistic. Please show us all columns on both tables and give us some ER information, where you'll hopefully find the link table. Otherwise you'll get a cartesian product of your rows.

Need help to see the actual result you want. Also: Show data as text, never as image.

Slightly offtopic: Using an integer array in your table, is not the best approach for a relational database. Stick to a 3NF model.

Just do a simple JOIN.
I need more information about t.tag_list & t.features_id,are these two fields calculated?If not,duplicating is normal.
SELECT 
  bs.id, bs.title_banner, bs.text_banner, bs.url_banner, bs.banner_state, bs.created_at, bs.updated_at, t.tag_list, t.features_id 
FROM 
  history_banenrs bs 
JOIN 
  history_features  t 
ON 
  bs.id_banner = t.id_banner;
WHERE 
  bs.id_banner = 51


Going out on a limb, this may be what you want - for a single, given id_banner:
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT id, title_banner, text_banner, url_banner, banner_state, created_at, updated_at
   FROM   history_banenrs
   WHERE  id_banner = 51
   ORDER  BY id   -- or whatever selects the best row
   LIMIT  1
   ) b
CROSS JOIN  (
   SELECT id_banner, tag_list, features_id
   FROM   history_features
   WHERE  id_banner = 51
   ORDER  BY id   -- or whatever selects the best row
   LIMIT  1
   ) t;

You get a single row - if both tables have any qualifying rows.
The CROSS JOIN eliminates rows where not both tables have a match. You may want to use FULL JOIN instead to preserve results where the other side is missing.
Should be as fast as it gets - with an index on (id_banner) for either table. If there are many dupes, make it a multicolumn index on (id_banner, id).
